# Integration of pandas timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to integrate the following dataframe, such that I have the integrated value for every hour. I have roughly a 10s sampling rate, but if it is necissary to have an even timeinterval, I guess I can just use `df.resample()`.

```
Timestamp                    Power [W]
2022-05-05 06:00:05+02:00    2.0
2022-05-05 06:00:15+02:00    1.2
2022-05-05 06:00:25+02:00    0.3
2022-05-05 06:00:35+02:00    4.3
2022-05-05 06:00:45+02:00    1.1
                            ... 
2022-05-06 20:59:19+02:00    1.4
2022-05-06 20:59:29+02:00    2.0
2022-05-06 20:59:39+02:00    4.1
2022-05-06 20:59:49+02:00    1.3
2022-05-06 20:59:59+02:00    0.8
```

So I want to be able to integrate over both hours and days, so my output could look like:

```
Timestamp                    Energy [Wh]
2022-05-05 07:00:00+02:00    some values
2022-05-05 08:00:00+02:00    .
2022-05-05 09:00:00+02:00    .
2022-05-05 10:00:00+02:00    .
2022-05-05 11:00:00+02:00    
                            ... 
2022-05-06 20:00:00+02:00    
2022-05-06 21:00:00+02:00
```

(hour 07:00 is to include values between 06:00-07:00, and so on...)

and

```
Timestamp      Energy [Wh]
2022-05-05     .
2022-05-06     .
```

So how do I achieve this? I was thinking I could use `scipy.integrate`, but my outputs look a bit weird.

Thank you.

Comment: Your sampling rate appears way too long to achieve an integral with meaningful accuracy. The power fluctuates widely. Perhaps it's simplest to just group by hour and calculate the average of the watt values to get the watt hours for each hour.

Comment: The power output is just "dummy data". The main purpose of this is to compare total energy output of different models. Why would sampling rate be too long?

Comment: The problem is that your power function appears very erratic. You don't really know what it looks like in between the sampling points. The delta from one timestamp to the next should be significantly smaller than the value itself. If that's not possible, you should at least take advantage of the law of large numbers and have way more than five observations per hour to get a meaningful number for the energy for each hour.

Comment: I see your point regarding an erratic function, and the values in my examples might be somewhat miss representative, but that shouldn't matter as for how to solve my problem in coding. And I do have more than 10 observation; one observation every 10 seconds makes for 360 observation an hour.

Comment: LOL I mixed up seconds with minutes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new column representing your Timestamp truncated to hours:

```
df['Timestamp_hour'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('h')
```

Please note that in that case, the rows between hour 6.00 to hour 6.59 will be included into the 6 hour and not the 7 one.

Then you can group your rows by your new column before applying your integration computation:

```py
df_integrated_hour = (
    df
    .groupby('Timestamp_hour')
    .agg({
        'Power': YOUR_INTEGRATION_FUNCTION
    })
    .rename(columns={'Power': 'Energy'})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: so could YOUR_INTEGRATION_FUNCTION be e.g `integrate.trapz()` here?

Comment: This doesn't work as it will throw 6-7 am of May 5 and May 6 in the same group.

Comment: Indeed @Joooeey, my bad! `.dt.floor('h')` will truncate the Timestamp to the hour granularity :)

Comment: @UPetit sweet I was looking for something like that. That's definitely simpler than what I did. You can edit your post and include this ;)

Comment: Thanks! It almost gives me what I'm after! I'm still a bit at a loss as for how to implement "YOUR_INTEGRATION_FUNCTION". integral.trapz assumes dx=1, and gives super high integrated values. I could plug in `dx = 1/360`, but each hour does not have exactly 360 values. How do I tackle that?

Comment: Hey @elsa, you could use the length of each group (= hour) to compute your dx dynamically like:
```df_integrated_hour = (
    df
    .groupby('Timestamp_hour')
    .apply({
        'Power': lambda x: scipy.integrate.trapz(x, dx=1/len(x))
    })
    .rename(columns={'Power': 'Energy'})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to give reasonable solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple solution using rectangle integration with rectangles spaced in 10 second intervals starting at zero and therefore NOT centered exactly on the data points (assuming that the data is delivered in regular intervals and no data is missing), a.k.a. a simple average.

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd

times = pd.date_range('2022-05-05 06:00:04+02:00', '2022-05-06 21:00:00+02:00', freq='10S')
watts = random.rand(len(times)) * 5
df = pd.DataFrame(index=times, data=watts, columns=["Power [W]"])

hourly = df.groupby([df.index.date, df.index.hour]).mean()
hourly.columns = ["Energy [Wh]"]
print(hourly)

hours_in_a_day = 24  # add special casing for leap days here, if required
daily = df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
daily.columns = ["Energy [Wh]"]
print(daily)
```

Output:

```
               Energy [Wh]
2022-05-05 6      2.625499
           7      2.365678
           8      2.579349
           9      2.569170
           10     2.543611
           11     2.742332
           12     2.478145
           13     2.444210
           14     2.507821
           15     2.485770
           16     2.414057
           17     2.567755
           18     2.393725
           19     2.609375
           20     2.525746
           21     2.421578
           22     2.520466
           23     2.653466
2022-05-06 0      2.559110
           1      2.519032
           2      2.472282
           3      2.436023
           4      2.378289
           5      2.549572
           6      2.558478
           7      2.470721
           8      2.429454
           9      2.390543
           10     2.538194
           11     2.537564
           12     2.492308
           13     2.387632
           14     2.435582
           15     2.581616
           16     2.389549
           17     2.461523
           18     2.576084
           19     2.523577
           20     2.572270
            Energy [Wh]
2022-05-05    60.597007
2022-05-06    59.725029
```

Trapezoidal integration should give a slightly better approximation but it's harder to implement right. You'd have to deal carefully with the hour boundaries. That's basically just a matter of inserting interpolated values twice at the full hour (at 09:59:59.999 and 10:00:00). But then you'd also have to figure out a way to extrapolate to the start and end of the range, i.e. in your example go from 06:00:05 to 06:00:00. But careful, what to do if your measurements only start somewhere in the middle like 06:17:23?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a package called [staircase](https://www.staircase.dev), which is part of the pandas ecosystem and exists to make working with step functions (i.e. piecewise constant) easier.

It will create a `Stairs` object (which represents a step function) from a `pandas.Series`, then bin across arbitrary `DatetimeIndex` values, then integrate.

**This solution requires `staircase 2.4.2` or above**

**setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Timestamp":pd.to_datetime(
            [
                "2022-05-05 06:00:05+02:00",
                "2022-05-05 06:00:15+02:00",
                "2022-05-05 06:00:25+02:00",
                "2022-05-05 06:00:35+02:00",
                "2022-05-05 06:00:45+02:00",
            ]
        ),
        "Power [W]":[2.0, 1.2, 0.3, 4.3, 1.1]
    }
)
```

**solution**

```
import staircase as sc

# create step function
sf = sc.Stairs.from_values(
    initial_value=0,
    values=df.set_index("Timestamp")["Power [W]"],
)

# optional: plot
sf.plot(style="hlines")
```

[image: step function plot]

```
# create the bins (datetime index) over which you want to integrate
# using 20s intervals in this example
bins = pd.date_range(
    "2022-05-05 06:00:00+02:00", "2022-05-05 06:01:00+02:00", freq="20s"
)

# slice into bins and integrate
result = sf.slice(bins).integral()
```

`result` will be a `pandas.Series` with an `IntervalIndex` and `Timedelta` values.  The IntervalIndex retains timezone info, it just doesn't display it:

```
[2022-05-05 06:00:00, 2022-05-05 06:00:20)          0 days 00:00:26
[2022-05-05 06:00:20, 2022-05-05 06:00:40)   0 days 00:00:30.500000
[2022-05-05 06:00:40, 2022-05-05 06:01:00)          0 days 00:00:38
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

You can change the index to be the "left" values (and see this timezone info) like this:

```
result.index = result.index.left
```

You can change values to a float with division by an appropriate `Timedelta`.  Eg to convert to minutes:

```
result/pd.Timedelta("1min")
```

**note**:
I am the creator of staircase.  Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.